# Rsync from NFS to remote server - not syncing files anymore

Tags: linux, debian, rsync

I'm having some real issues trying to rsync a large amount of MP3 files (3.5TB worth) from an NFS mounted partition to a remote server using a Debian cloud based node. It appeared to sync a lot of files at first but now it's stopped syncing.

The directory is constantly updated with files so I know there will be files that should be synced. This is what happens whenever I try and sync:

```
root@node:/# rsync -Pav -e 'ssh -i /keyfile.pem' /nfs/src ubuntu@ec2:/dest
sending incremental file list
./

sent 2332901 bytes  received 75 bytes  15710.28 bytes/sec
total size is 529754905288  speedup is 227072.59
```

When usually it would show progress, it no longer shows any files being transferred. The newly updated files on the NFS mount can be accessed directly without problems.

I've updated rsync to the latest 3.1.2 but still no luck.